# Display a certain cell in a table view based on some logic

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have tableview and some of the cells are off screen. I am working on letting a user reorder the list but sometimes the current one is then off screen.  A rough example would be how emails works.  If you are on a message and resort by sender instead of date, the message you are currently stays on the list of messages.

In swift is there a way for me to scroll the table view down or something so that a certain cell is visible on screen?  Right now I only know how to resort the data array and reload the table... what I want is to have a certain cell guaranteed on screen after the reloaded table.

If I were to construct this as an exercise I would present an array of 10 names with a 1-10 id where only 5 can be on screen.  Once a tableview cell is tapped the id for "currentlySelected" is saved.  Place 2 buttons at the top where  sorts by name and <123> by id

If I selected 2-steve and then clicked the ABC button...  how can I make it so that  2-steve is on the screen since only 5 names can show on the screen at a time and steve is ABC ordered as position 7?

```
<ABC>    <123>
1-dan
2-steve
3-ted
4-carol
5-anne
6-tony
7-linda
8-chris
9-blake
10- tom
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614997-scrolltorow or https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614910-scrolltonearestselectedrow

Answer (score 1):

If you know the Index Path of the Cell you want to scroll to, just use the Table View provided method:

```
if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
    self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
}
```

Or, generally:

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0)
self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
```

Note: the row should be a value in [0...9] range in your case.